# Output from FORMAT to a string?

Tags: database, common-lisp, string-formatting

just recently I have been playing around with lisp, and I'm trying to create a generic local database, I'm following another tutorial that covers the majority of this type of project, however I decided that I wanted to add in a "simple" feature.

I'm trying to generate timestamps in a custom format, and to save them to a string.  I'm trying to store the string generated by **format** into a variable declared with **defvar** by calling **format** with the variable as the first argument, but instead of saving the full output, I just get the day of the month. Here is my code:

```
(defun date ()

    (setq *SUPPRESS-SIMILAR-CONSTANT-REDEFINITION-WARNING* 1)
    (defconstant *day-names*
    '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))
    *DAY-NAMES*

    (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
        (get-decoded-time)
    (defvar datetime)   
    (format datetime "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
    hour
    minute
    second
    (nth day-of-week *day-names*)
    month
    date
    year
    (- tz)
    (return-from date datetime))))

(defun make-entry (category subject idea info researched)
    (defvar date (date))
    (list :category category :subject subject :date date :idea idea :info info :researched researched))
```

The expected value of **date** inside **make-entry** should be similar to **21:28:18 Wednesday 7/30/2014 (GMT-7)**, but I end up with only 30, not the rest of it. Also I have tested to find the type of the returned 30, and it is indeed an integer, not a char-stream(string) as it should be. Because of this I am convinced this has something to do with the "~d"'s in format, however I may be wrong. Really, I'm just trying to pass a formatted version of the system time to make-entry.

Comment: You're not trying to "save it to a stream" (I'm not sure what that would be, except maybe that it could be read from a stream later);  you're trying to get the output in a *string*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok then. [Dons code-review hat]

---

Firstly, lets indent that just a touch more consistently. You did do much better than the typical lisp-newbie does at indentation, but flushed most of it down one column. Indentation level can give you a lot of hints as to the control flow of your program. Once you're used to it, I mean.

```
(defun date ()

  (setq *SUPPRESS-SIMILAR-CONSTANT-REDEFINITION-WARNING* 1)
  (defconstant *day-names*
    '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))
  *DAY-NAMES*

  (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (defvar datetime)   
    (format datetime "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
            hour minute second
            (nth day-of-week *day-names*)
            month date year
            (- tz)
            (return-from date datetime))))

(defun make-entry (category subject idea info researched)
  (defvar date (date))
  (list :category category :subject subject :date date :idea idea :info info :researched researched))
```

---

You *can* but shouldn't use `defconstant` and `defvar` locally. Either make those top-level forms, or make them local definitions by using `let`. In your case, the `constant` makes sense as a global, while the `var` should probably be a local variable (but more on that later). Also, now that you're not redefining a constant on each function call, you don't need to squelch that redefinition warning.

```
(defconstant *day-names* '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))

(defun date ()
  *DAY-NAMES*

  (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (let ((datetime))
      (format datetime "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
              hour minute second
              (nth day-of-week *day-names*)
              month date year
              (- tz)
              (return-from date datetime)))))
```

---

A Lisp form automatically returns the last value it computes, but any earlier forms will only produce side-effects as opposed to values. Specifically `*DAY-NAMES*` does nothing at the beginning of `date`. Also, since you seem to be trying to return `datetime` from `date`, you don't need to call `return-from`. Rather, just evaluate `datetime`.

```
(defun date ()
  (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (let ((datetime))
      (format datetime "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
              hour minute second
              (nth day-of-week *day-names*) 
              month date year
              (- tz))
      datetime)))
```

---

`format` takes a stream as its first argument. And a variable is not a stream (though it might contain one; yours doesn't). What you seem to want to do here is return the current time as a string, formatted according to your `format` directives. To do that, you need no intermediate value at all. Just pass `NIL` as the first argument to `format`, and it'll automatically create a new string with your contents, and return it.

```
(defun date ()
  (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
            hour minute second
            (nth day-of-week *day-names*) 
            month date year
            (- tz))))
```

At this point, `date` seems to do something meaningful.

```
cl-user> (date)
"15:39:12 Thursday 7/31/2014 (GMT-5)"
cl-user>
```

---

Since you're just trying to put some values into a list, you also don't need to create a local variable to hold the result of `(date)` in `make-entry`.

```
(defun make-entry (category subject idea info researched)
  (list :category category :subject subject :date (date) :idea idea :info info :researched researched))
```

At this point, `make-entry` returns a `plist` whose `:DATE` value is the appropriate formatted string from `date`.

```
cl-user> (make-entry "something" "something else" "blah" "bleeh" "stop using side effects")
(:CATEGORY "something" :SUBJECT "something else" :DATE
 "15:41:57 Thursday 7/31/2014 (GMT-5)" :IDEA "blah" :INFO "bleeh" :RESEARCHED
 "stop using side effects")
cl-user>
```

---

```
(defconstant *day-names* '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))

(defun date ()
  (multiple-value-bind
        (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
            hour minute second
            (nth day-of-week *day-names*) 
            month date year
            (- tz))))

(defun make-entry (category subject idea info researched)
  (list :category category :subject subject :date (date) :idea idea :info info :researched researched))
```

---

If you're following along with [the PCL database chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html), keep in mind that the date you're formatting in this manner will need to be decoded again when you read your database in, assuming you're planning on doing anything other than string comparisons with it. So depending on your specific use case, it may actually make more sense to store the raw output of `(get-universal-time)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defconstant *day-names* 
  '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))

(defun date ()
  (multiple-value-bind
      (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (declare (ignore dst-p))
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
            hour minute second
            (nth day-of-week *day-names*)
            month date year (- tz))))

(defun make-entry (category subject idea info researched)
  (list :category category 
        :subject subject 
        :date (date) 
        :idea idea 
        :info info 
        :researched researched))
```

then

```
? (date)
"21:13:25 Thursday 7/31/2014 (GMT+1)"
? (make-entry "Lisp" "format" "read more" "CLHS" "not yet")
(:CATEGORY "Lisp" :SUBJECT "format" :DATE "21:19:42 Thursday 7/31/2014 (GMT+1)" :IDEA "read more" :INFO "CLHS" :RESEARCHED "not yet")
```

Some remarks:

1. declare constants outside of functions
2. don't use `defvar` to declare local variables, this doesn't do what you think - use `let`, or even better, avoid them
3. don't use `return-from` here; the function returns the last evaluated form, in this case the result of `format`
4. nitpicking: if you have unused variables you cannot avoid, use `(declare (ignore ...))` in order to avoid compilation errors

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of issues with this code, but the biggest one is that one of the arguments to `format` is `(return-from …)`:

```
(format datetime "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)"
    hour
    minute
    second
    (nth day-of-week *day-names*)
    month
    date
    year
    (- tz)
    (return-from date datetime))
```

Compare this with:

```
CL-USER> (defun foo ()
           (list 1 2 3 (return-from foo 4)))
FOO
CL-USER> (foo)
4
```

Most of the time you don't need to do anything special to return a value from a function;  value of the last expression is the result of the function.  Something like this suffices, since when the first argument to **format** is **nil**, you get a string back:

```
(defconstant +day-names+                       ; Some people put + around constants
  '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday"             ; but it's not as a strong a convention
    "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"))  ; as * around dynamic variables.

(defun date ()
  (multiple-value-bind (second minute hour date month year day-of-week dst-p tz)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (declare (ignore dst-p))
    ;; The value of (format ...) is returned from the date.
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d ~a ~d/~2,'0d/~d (GMT~@d)" 
            hour minute second
            (nth day-of-week +day-names+)
            month date year (- tz))))
```

```
CL-USER> (date)
"15:36:40 Thursday 7/31/2014 (GMT-5)"
```

As an aside, while this works, it might be more useful for you in the long run to use dates that are formatted in some external standard, e.g., as specified by XSD dateTimes.  For that, you might find external libraries, like some of [those for time listed on CLiki](http://www.cliki.net/time) useful.